# how to change hash section of shadow file by using c language(programmatically)?

Tags: c, file, hash

I need to change hash section by app.

the below image is my shadow file:

[image]

after running app, hash section will be change like below image.

[image]

the below code work, but I need two thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main() {
    system("cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow_old");
    FILE* shadow = fopen("/etc/shadow_old","r+");
    if (shadow == NULL)
    { 
        printf ("Cannot open shadow file \n");
        return -1; 
    } 

    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0; 
    char* delimiter= ":";
    ssize t read;
    int ret = 0; 
    char key[] = "root:";
    char value[] = "M0686fd1d172ba1:!!:118 ..... 9::::";
    char* pch = NULL; 

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, shadow)) != -1)
    { 
        pch = NULL; 
        pch = strstr(line, key);
        printf("pos: U\n",ftell(shadow)); 
        if(pch) 
        { 
            printf("pch--> %s\n",pch);
            printf("current password--> %s\n",pch+(strlen(key)+strlen(delimiter)));
            fseek(shadow,-strlen(line),SEEK_CUR);
            printf("pos after fseek: U\n",ftell(shadow));
            break: 
        }
    }

    if (line) 
    { 
        int lenOfLine=strlen(line); 
        char* str=(char*) malloc (lenOfLine);
        memset(str,' ',lenOfLine); 
        if(value!=NULL)
        { 
            fwrite(key,1,sizeof(key),shadow);
            fwrite(value,1,sizeof(value),shadow);
        }
        free(str); 
    }

    fclose(shadow); 

    return 0;
}
```

1: when my hash is less than before, hash not replaced completely

2: I need general solution, I think my code is dirty.

thanks for adv. appreciate

Comment: 1. Please update your question and replace your images with text.  2. /etc/shadow is only readable by root for security reasons.  3. Don't use `system()`.  4. Use `getspent()` or friends to read data and `putspent()` to set it.

Comment: You want to read n bytes, write m (m < n), then read the next chunk and write it to fill the gap.  Don't use`fseek()`.  Or read the whole file, write the prefix, write the new chunk, write the suffix.  In general read from /etc/shadow write to to /etc/shadow.new, then rename the new file to the original name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9706/allan-wind the second pic is text 2 that hash section of root user has updated.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but if I wanted to help you I would have to type that in by hand when it's an image opposed to copy and paste if it was text.  You want to make it as easy as possible for someone to help you.

Comment: I know what you are saying an I appreciate. below text can be replacement text.
root:abcdef1234567890
it does not matter what text is inside file, it can be anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the below code is all I need.

1: I found the specific line according to key params.
2: I rewind file pointer
3: read all character and write it to replica file except the specific line.
4: rename the replica file name.

```
const char* filename="/etc/shadow_old";  //just change shadow_old to shadow.

const char* filenameReplica="/etc/shadow_replica";

int renamePassword(const char* key,const char* value){

    system("cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow_old");
    
    FILE* shadow = fopen(filename,"r+");
    FILE* replica = fopen(filenameReplica,"w");;
    if (shadow == NULL  || replica == NULL)
        {
            printf ("Cannot open shadow file \n");
            return -1;
        }

    

    int lineCounter=1;
    int lineNumber=0;

    char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        char* delimiter= ":";
        ssize_t read;
        int ret = 0;
        char* pch = NULL;
    char* token = NULL;
    short userFound=0;
    
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, shadow)) != -1)
        {
        pch = NULL;
            pch = strstr(line, key);
        
            if(pch)
        {   
            lineNumber=lineCounter;
            userFound=1;
        }else lineCounter++;
    }

    char ch='A';
    int tmp=1;
    rewind(shadow);
    while((ch =getc(shadow))!=EOF){
        //ch =getc(shadow);
        //printf("ch: %c\n",ch);
        if(tmp != lineNumber)
        {
            putc(ch,replica);
        }
        if(ch=='\n')
        {   
            tmp++;
        }
    }

    int lenOfReplacement=strlen(value); 
    int lenOfKey = strlen(key);
    char* tmpValue=(char*) malloc (lenOfKey+lenOfReplacement+1);
    strncpy(tmpValue,key,lenOfKey);
    strncpy(tmpValue + lenOfKey,value,lenOfReplacement);
    tmpValue[lenOfKey+lenOfReplacement+1]='\0';

    printf("tmpValue-->  %s\n",tmpValue);
    //fwrite("\n",1,strlen("\n"),replica); //uncomment this line if you want to change multiple user not only one user. this line create new line in shadow file(no bad effect).
    fwrite(tmpValue,1,strlen(tmpValue),replica);
    free(tmpValue);
    

    fclose(shadow);
    fclose(replica);
    remove(filename);
    rename(filenameReplica,filename);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Prefer using `getspent()` and `putspent()`.  They will lock the file so any concurrent writes won't result in data loss.
2. Don't use `system()`.  It makes your program non-portable for no good reason.
3. `fopen(..., "w")` will truncate an existing file.  Prefer using temporary path name with a random path.
4. Don't use `fseek()` when making changes.  It will either leave the hole (like you saw) or result in data being overwritten if the `new` string is larger than the `old`.
5. Create a temporary file and to it copy the prefix (however many lines), `new` string, and suffix.  Then rename the temporary file to the original file name.  The implementation below changes all matches.  `memmem()` is probably a little faster than `strstr()` but either would work here.   You could use `fwrite()` instead of `fprint()` but it's a little fiddly to check for errors that are signaled with a short write.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEMPLATE "XXXXXX"

int file_str_replace(const char *path, const char *old, const char *new) {
    FILE *dst = NULL;
    char dsttmp[strlen(path) + sizeof(TEMPLATE)];
    *dsttmp = '\0';
    FILE *src;
    char *line = NULL;
    if(!(src = fopen(path, "r")))
        goto err;
    strcpy(dsttmp, path);
    strcat(dsttmp, TEMPLATE);
    int fd = mkstemp(dsttmp);
    if(fd == -1) {
        *dsttmp = '\0';
        goto err;
    }
    dst = fdopen(fd, "w");
    if(!dst)
        goto err;

    size_t old_len = strlen(old);
    size_t new_len = strlen(new);
    size_t line_len = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &line_len, src) != -1) {
        char *found = memmem(line, line_len, old, old_len);
        if(found) {
            // prefix old suffix
            // ^line            ^ line + line_len
            //        ^found
            int rv = fprintf(dst, "%.*s%.*s%.*s",
                (int) (found - line),
                line,
                (int) new_len,
                new,
                (int) (line_len - (found + old_len - line)),
                found + old_len
            );
            if(rv < 0)
                goto err;
            continue;
        }
        int rv = fprintf(dst, "%.*s", (int) line_len, line);
        if(rv < 0)
            goto err;
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);
    rename(dsttmp, path);
    return 0;
err:
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    free(line);
    if(dst) fclose(dst);
    if(*dsttmp) remove(dsttmp); // prefer unlink() but it's unistd.h
    if(src) fclose(src);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    file_str_replace("shadow", "old", "new");
}
```

and example run:

```
$ cat shadow && ./a.out && cat shadow
prefix old suffix
prefix new suffix
```

Comment: dear allan thanks for response , nice points.

Comment: Implied when accepting answer and/or upvote.